# Highlighting Sub topic in a post?

Tags: wp-query, customization, query

Have seen this sub topics highlighter in many blogs. It gives a special attraction to a sub topics used in the post.

Is this a plugin or part of code? How can I add this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl3TB.jpg

Comment: The link is the preview of the code am looking for.

Comment: Sorry, the image adds no clarity to this question. It would be more helpful to have a link to the site and not to the screenshot.

Comment: check out the sub topics in the link. http://www.shoutmeloud.com/ideas-for-blog-content.html

Comment: That is nothing but the theme's CSS, which you can see here: http://www.shoutmeloud.com/wp-content/themes/SML/custom/custom.css?9792e1. Look for `.note` in the stylesheet. But pure CSS questions off-topic here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. But am looking for a plugin or a code which can help me with adding this note every time I write a post.

Comment: All you have to do is styling `h3` elements, maybe with a class: `h3.subtopic{ background: url(img.png) left center no-repeat #99f}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But am looking for a plugin or a code which can help me with adding
>   this note every time I write a post.

A shortcode to add that "note" is trivial.

```
function note_sc_wpse_107275($atts,$content) {
  return '<p class="note"><strong>'.$content.'</strong></p>';
}
add_shortcode('note','note_sc_wpse_107275');
```

Then just add `[note]Note content[/note]` to your post body.

That will give you exactly what you see on that site, assuming that I am looking at the right piece of it. By default, it won't look like anything special. You will need to add style rules to decorate it however you like.