# How do I add text in a shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode

I think this might be an easier question but I can't figure it out.

How can I add simple text inside a short code?

For example:

```
$return_string .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><div>'.read more.'</div></a>';
```

So, I don't just want to return text, but I want to return text and a link. I am using this shortcode to query the posts, but I want to add a "read more" link after each excerpt, but I cant figure out how to just add the text "read more."

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to create a shortcode with the above output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting Sub topic in a post?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107275/highlighting-sub-topic-in-a-post)

Comment: I checked out the other topic and I don't think it is the same, but perhaps I am wrong....I will be a little more accurate in my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hello you can try this

```
// Add Shortcode
function text_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {
  // Code
  return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'b', 'text_shortcode' );
```

The shortcode will be something like this

```
[b] content [/b]
```

Comment: Won't I need to define `$content` somewhere? would it look like this: `$content = 'read more'`?

Comment: you will pass it in the shortcode, for example in the post you will have [b]this is the content[/b] ... if it's null then in the function you can assign a default value. $content = something.