# How to create shortcode of this PHP code

Tags: php, shortcode

I tried a lot but failed to create shortcode of this PHP snippet:

```
<ul>
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_status=future&order=DESC&showposts=10');
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

    <?php endwhile;
}
?>
</ul>
```

Can you tell me how to do that & also explain how to put PHP codes into shortcodes. Don't need to explain the basic as I know how to create a shortcode.

Comment: Where is your attempt to create a shortcode? There are any number of Q/As on this site that should answer this question. For example, [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107282/21376).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it..

```
   function future_posts_function($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'poststatus' => 'future',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'showposts' => 10,
    ), $atts));

    $return_string = '<ul>';
    query_posts(array('post_status' => $poststatus, 'order' => $order, 'showposts' => $showposts));
    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $return_string .= '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $return_string .= '</ul>';

    wp_reset_query();
    return $return_string;
}
add_shortcode('future_posts', 'future_posts_function');
```

Comment: It's showing the published posts. However, the code I posted is showing future posts when I used it as a page template.

Comment: Try... <pre><?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_status=future'  ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?></pre>